# TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, dictionary, components

Newbie to React and I need help again - everything was fine untill i shifted the code from App.js to separate component - and b/c it is the stateless component, i am using props and map function to access the value and state from App.js but it is not happy -- help please

```
import React from 'react';

const Recipes = props => (
  <div>
    {props.recipes.map(recipe => (
        <div key={recipe.recipe_id}>
          <img src={recipe.image_url} alt={recipe.title} />
          <p>{recipe.title}</p>
        </div>
    ))}
    </div>
);

export default Recipes;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This just means that you don't pass in `recipes` properly as a prop where you render `<Recipes />`. Either `recipes` is null or incorrectly formatted.

ex:

```
// App.js

import React from 'react';

const App = () => {
  const recipes = [{
    recipe_id: '<id>',
    image_url: '<some url>',
    title: 'Lé title'
  }];

  // recipes could be null/undefined or not even passed as a prop

  return (
    <Recipes recipes={recipes} />
  );
}
export default App;
```

Comment: so state is an empty array of  `recipe`. How am I passing it  `<Recipes recipes={this.state.recipes} />' so when i want to pass it to the components via `props` is should have the access to the `state` in main component?? Isn't so? or did i get the concept wrong? @Brendon

Comment: I think you understand the concept correctly but I am not sure exactly what is wrong. Can you post the parent component that you are rendering `<Recipes />` in? I might be able to help more if I can see that.

Comment: Here is a small code sandbox if you want to see how the state might work from the parent. https://codesandbox.io/s/vy8qx67207

Comment: I added the https://codesandbox.io/s/38xy0642yq code for App.js and the recipes.js Thanks @Brandon

Comment: In your code sandbox, the state in your component is `recipe` and not `recipes`. When you pass `this.state.recipe`, you are actually passing undefined. It should be `this.state.recipes`

Answer (score 1):

So it's hard to know exactly what's happening without being able to see how you are passing down props, and exactly what data they contain. The error you are getting implies that you aren't actually sending the recipes array correctly.

I honestly never use stateless functions in react anymore, because PureComponent generally preforms better because of it's built in shouldComponentUpdate which prevents unnecessary re-renders. So here's how I would write that component:

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';

class Recipes extends PureComonent {
  recipeList = () => {
    const recipes = this.props;
    const recipeArray = recipes.map((recipe) => {
      <div key={recipe.recipe_id}>
        <img src={recipe.image_url} alt={recipe.title} />
        <p>{recipe.title}</p>
      </div>
    });
    return recipeArray;
  }

  render () {
    return () {
      <div>
        {this.recipeList()}
      </div>
    }
  }
}

export default Recipes;
```

That being said, my guess about the way you wrote your component is that if you were to console out props you would find that it was actually equal to recipes, which is why recipes.recipes is undefined.

Comment: Exactly, so the props are giving me the array i need in console in the main component. But as soon as I separated it in the different component, which is stateless, which i can use the function method instead of class, i still shiuld be able to access the state from main via passing down the props as argument? Am i wrong somewhere in grabbing the concept?